# Erro ao publicar versão em produção no azure

Tags: c#, microsoft-azure, storage

Estou tentando publicar uma versão no azure de uma determinada aplicação e sempre acusa esse erro, antes subia sem probelmas. Rodando local a aplicação funciona sem problemas. O que devo verificar ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é saída após a compilação
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo(a) à plataforma. E, desde já, sujiro a leitura dos seguintes artigos: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1). Ambos artigos, vos ensinará como elaborar uma boa pergunta, evitando com isso, votos negativos e, até mesmo, de fechamento. Boa sorte! Aproveite todo nosso potencial, volte sempre e forte abraço.